# "The given key was not present in the dictionary" nHibernate C#

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Am pretty new to nHibernate. I've setup the following one-to-one mapping between two tables "User" and "UserProfile".

User.hbm.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"           namespace="Core.Domain.Model" assembly="Core">

  <class name="User" table="Users" dynamic-update="true" lazy="false">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="UserId" column="UserId" type="guid">
    </id>
    <one-to-one name="UserProfile" class="UserProfile"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

UserProfile.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Core.Domain.Model" assembly="Core">
<class name="UserProfile" table="UserProfiles" dynamic-update="true" lazy="false">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id name="UserProfileId" column="UserProfileId" type="int">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Description" length="100"/>
  <many-to-one name="User" unique="true" column="UserId"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My POCOs for the above mappings are:

```
public class User
    {
        public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    }

public class UserProfile
    {
        public virtual int UserProfileId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Now when I attempt to persist my "User" object I get an exception: 
"**The given key was not present in the dictionary**" on the following line:

```
using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
```

Does anyone know what could be going on here?

Comment: I've seen this error before I think.  Try rebuilding your app, and running it again.  See what the first exception that gets thrown is.

Comment: Could you show as code that dose persist User...

Comment: Just did. It throws the same exception.

Comment: @Darius I am not sure whether the problem is with the persistence code. It actually never gets to session.save(). I am thinking it might be something to do with the mapping itself.

Comment: Are you sure it's ok to have a one-to-one association in one direction and a many-to-one association in the other direction?

Comment: @Ilya I believe thats the way its done in NH. Am following this blog entry http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/19/nhibernate-mapping-ltone-to-onegt.aspx for mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied your hbm mappings and your classes into my test project. I got the error when creating the SessionFactory. Any chance, that you are creating the SessionFactory when first accessing it in your using-Statement? If so, then this will hopefully solve the issue:

I fixed it by adding

```
public virtual String Description { get; set; }
```

to the UserProfile class. 
If you have that in your code and just forgot that during copy&paste, I'll try to investigate further.

**Edit:**

Another possible source for this error - as found [here](http://codebetter.com/kylebaley/2008/03/15/nhibernate-error-while-adding-a-collection-to-an-object/):

Please verify that all your .hbm.xml files are embedded resources.

If that still does not help, could you please post the StackTrace of the exception?

Comment: Ah yes I have that. Copy-Paste blunder. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @kartikq If this answer helped you, why didn't you select it as the chosen answer, or at least vote it up?

Comment: @kartikq if this answer solves your problem then you should accept it as answer not upvote...

Comment: Same problem here, also with an one-to-one relationship, thanks @Florian Lim, the problem was my mapping, it wasn't as an embedded resource.

Comment: I already check my classes but it wasn't solve by that. Any solutions aside from that?

Answer (score 0):

The error is ambiguous.

In my case it was because of a dynamically generated HQL statement that had a missing HQL `where` clause, though it had conditions.

That is, the WRONGLY generated HQL was something like

> ```
> from User u
>   left join u.Profile
>     (id = :id)
> ```

Somewhere in the chain of building up the query, there was a missing `where` clause. So that it becomes:

> ```
> from User u
>   left join u.Profile
>     where (id = :id)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem! For me it was the same like kerzek said, a one to one reference with different column names. I added the constrained="false"to the one to one mapping:

```
<one-to-one name="Person" class="PersonClass" cascade="none" constrained="false" fetch="join"/>
```